# Java buffer strategy loses hardware acceleration

Tags: java, graphics, buffer, acceleration

I am working on a Java game engine and when I switch to the Windows log in screen and return, the buffer strategy loses it's hardware acceleration. Nothing I do will restore the buffer to hardware accelerated again until I shut down the program and restart it.

Here are a number of propertied for ((Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()).getDeviceConfiguration() when the program is started.

```
Bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1440,height=900]
Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DBufferCaps@114b82b
   Back Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@147358f
      Accelerated: true
      True Volatile: true
   Flip Contents: undefined
   Front Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@147358f
      Accelerated: true
      True Volatile: true
   Is Full Screen Required: false
   Is MultiBuffer Available: true
   Is Page Flipping: true
Device: D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=1]
   Available Accelerated Memory: 750780416
   ID String: \Display1
   Type: 0
   Display Mode: java.awt.DisplayMode@dd3
Image Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@147358f
   Accelerated: true
   True Volatile: true
```

Here are the same properties after the log in screen is displayed.

```
Bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=942,height=566]
Buffer Capabilities: java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration$DefaultBufferCapabilities@19d688
   Back Buffer Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@539a92
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
   Flip Contents: null
   Front Buffer Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@539a92
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
   Is Full Screen Required: false
   Is MultiBuffer Available: false
   Is Page Flipping: false
Device: sun.awt.image.BufferedImageDevice@c8f0a4
   Available Accelerated Memory: -1
   ID String: BufferedImage
   Type: 2
   Display Mode: java.awt.DisplayMode@68c
Image Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@539a92
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
```

The buffer capabilities change from *sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@147358f* to *java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration$DefaultBufferCapabilities@19d688*.  If have not found a way to return the buffer strategy to hardware accelerated. Disposing and creating the buffer strategy again does not restore the hardware acceleration.

The buffer strategy is created on a Canvas object. The ((Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()).getDeviceConfiguration() properties above lose the acceleration but when I get the GraphicsConfiguration on the Canvas object by calling canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration(), the Canvas object itself still shows it is accelerated.

Here are the properties for the canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration() while the graphics object from the buffer strategy is returning false for accelerated.

```
Bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1440,height=900]
Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DBufferCaps@1672113
   Back Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@d5eb7
      Accelerated: true
      True Volatile: true
   Flip Contents: undefined
   Front Buffer Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@d5eb7
      Accelerated: true
      True Volatile: true
   Is Full Screen Required: false
   Is MultiBuffer Available: true
   Is Page Flipping: true
Device: D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=1]
   Available Accelerated Memory: 764411904
   ID String: \Display1
   Type: 0
   Display Mode: java.awt.DisplayMode@dd3
Image Capabilities: sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsConfig$D3DImageCaps@d5eb7
   Accelerated: true
   True Volatile: true
```

Here is the code that can be used to reproduce the above described problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AccelerationTest extends JFrame {

    public AccelerationTest(){
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);       
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        createBufferStrategy(2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        (new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                do{
                    render();
                    try{Thread.sleep(200);}catch(InterruptedException e){}                          
                }while (true);                      
            }           
        })).start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AccelerationTest();     
            }
        });
    }

    private void render(){

        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

        graphic.setColor(Color.red);
        graphic.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphic.setColor(Color.white);
        graphic.fillRect((int) (getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (getHeight() * 0.1), (int) (getWidth() * 0.8), (int) (getHeight() * 0.8));

        bufferStrategy.show();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("graphic from frame: \n" + getDeviceConfigurationString(graphic.getDeviceConfiguration()));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("frame: \n" + getDeviceConfigurationString(getGraphicsConfiguration()));

       graphic.dispose();
    }

    private String getDeviceConfigurationString(GraphicsConfiguration gc){
        return "Bounds: " + gc.getBounds() + "\n" + 
                "Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "   Back Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" + 
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n" +
                "   Flip Contents: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFlipContents() + "\n" +
                "   Front Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" +
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n" +
                "   Is Full Screen Required: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isFullScreenRequired() + "\n" +
                "   Is MultiBuffer Available: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isMultiBufferAvailable() + "\n" +
                "   Is Page Flipping: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isPageFlipping() + "\n" +
                "Device: " + gc.getDevice() + "\n" +
                "   Available Accelerated Memory: " + gc.getDevice().getAvailableAcceleratedMemory() + "\n" +
                "   ID String: " + gc.getDevice().getIDstring() + "\n" +
                "   Type: " + gc.getDevice().getType() + "\n" +
                "   Display Mode: " + gc.getDevice().getDisplayMode() + "\n" +              
                "Image Capabilities: " + gc.getImageCapabilities() + "\n" + 
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getImageCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" + 
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getImageCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n";        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question can be disregarded. After testing the code outside of the project, I discovered that it was not the buffer strategy that was losing the hardware acceleration but a VolatileImage. While checking if the VolatileImage needed to be recreated, if isAccelerated returned false, the section was skipped. So during a screen change, acceleration appears to not be available but becomes available again but the code was skipping the section because the VolatileImage created was already created without acceleration.